# Undefined Control Sequence in bibtex

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I do not understand why my bibliography is not showing: I ran a very simple file to test it and I get the same error as in my main file.

```
\documentstyle{amsart}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{amsplain}
\bibliography{C:\Users\...\References}
\end{document}
```

I get on line 5 (`\bibliography`)

```
! Undefined control sequence.<write> \string \bibdata {C:\Users\...\Bibliography ... ...rdo\...\References}
```

I am running the correct sequence on TeXMaker to get the bibliography and I even did get an output on other files. the `bibtex` file is not in the same folder as the script, but there is no difference when they are together.
What is wrong?

**EDIT**

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \begin{document}
 \cite{Franceschini.2008}
 \bibliographystyle{amsplain}
 \bibliography{C:/Users/.../References}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Are you using `...` to mask the path in your MWE or you really have them in your document?

Comment: Can you give a minimal failing example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\Users` is an undefined command. Use `/` as the path separator.

Comment: That solves the error, thank you! But I still get no bibliography.
I cite one reference in the text, but I get the warning it is undefined and nothing is printed out at the end. I updated the MWE

Comment: @writingthesis have you run bibtex? then latex again?

Comment: @writingthesis but don't edit the question to ask a new question: That makes the site impossible for later readers to follow. If one question is answered move on, and if necessary ask a new question (but needing latex bibtex latex latex is a faq)

Comment: Yes. PdfLaTeX + BiB(la)TeX(x2) + PdfLaTeX(x2) + View Pdf

Comment: Sorry about it, I was just trying to solve this issue once and for all. I'll ask a new question if you prefer.
And `...` is there just to mask the path

Comment: @writingthesis biblatex(x2 )doesn't sound right, it should be bibtex and just once, but in any case this is unrelated to your original question. If bibtex is not making a bibliography it will leave an error message in the .blg log, in which case post a new question with a copy of that errro message.